# I'm trying to fatch data from array using map function in react. But id is not fetching. I use 'key' keyword, still got undefined id

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react trying to make a clone of amazon but I'm getting a Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
**Below is my code**

** This is my array page**

```
const productData = [
{
    id: 2,
    Heading : 'Book ticket for essential travel',
    img1 : aeroplane,
    p1 : 'Flight tickets',
    img2 : Essential,
    p2 : 'Essentail Travel product',
    img3 : Train,
    p3 : 'Train tickets',
    img4 : Bus,
    p4 : 'Bus tickets'
},
```

** This is my home page where I used map function **

```
 <div className="col-md-12">
      <div className="row">
        { 
             productData.map( (val) => 
                {
                  return(
                         <div className="col-md-3">
                             <Product 
                              key = {val.id}
                              Heading = {val.Heading}
                              img1 = {val.img1}
                              p1 = {val.p1}
                              img2 = {val.img2}
                              p2 = {val.p2}
                              img3 = {val.img3}
                              p3 = {val.p3}
                              img4 = {val.img4}
                              p4 = {val.p4}
                              />
                           </div>
                        )
                   } 
              )
          }
        </div>
      </div>
```

** This is my product page where I used props **

```
<div className="product">
        <h4>{props.Heading}</h4>
        <div className="inner_product" id={props.id}>
            <div className="">
                <img src={props.img1}/>
                <p>{props.p1}</p>
                <img src={props.img2} className="mr-4"/>
                <p>{props.p2}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="">
                <img src={props.img3}/>
                <p>{props.p3}</p>
                <img src={props.img4}/>
                <p>{props.p4}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button className="btn btn-warning" onClick={addToCart}>add to cart</button>
        <a href="#" className="product_link float-right">Expand more</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `key` prop should be assign to the parent component. See [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

```
<div className="col-md-3" key={val.id}>
  <Product ... >
</div>
```

Full example:

```
<div className="col-md-12">
  <div className="row">
    {productData.map((val) => {
      return (
        <div className="col-md-3" key={val.id}>
          <Product
            Heading={val.Heading}
            img1={val.img1}
            p1={val.p1}
            img2={val.img2}
            p2={val.p2}
            img3={val.img3}
            p3={val.p3}
            img4={val.img4}
            p4={val.p4}
          />
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>
</div>;
```

Answer (score 0):

The key needs to be at the first element in the loop

```
<div className="col-md-12">
  <div className="row">
    { 
         productData.map( (val) => 
            {
              return(
                     <div className="col-md-3" key={val.id}>
                         <Product 
                          Heading = {val.Heading}
                          img1 = {val.img1}
                          p1 = {val.p1}
                          img2 = {val.img2}
                          p2 = {val.p2}
                          img3 = {val.img3}
                          p3 = {val.p3}
                          img4 = {val.img4}
                          p4 = {val.p4}
                          />
                       </div>
                    )
               } 
          )
      }
    </div>
  </div>
```